# Android: Strange text alignment issue seen on KitKat (API 19) but not on Gingerbread (API 10)

Tags: android

I have been experiencing an issue during testing and I am unsure what the cause maybe. 
My custom list view which contains some text views and a button is having an issue where the aligning of the button text (raffles) is not centre aligned which varies between devices.

**Picture taken from HTC explorer (API 10)**

[image]

**Picture taken from HTC one mini (API 19)**

[image]

The pictures show that the raffle text is not center aligned.

Here is the XML code for that particular button (note that the parent layout is a relative layout)

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/bCheckRaffle"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvSet2One"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvSet2One"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Raffles"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

here is some of the stuff I tried but had no effect

- Gravity as center_vertical and center_horizontal
- Removed the button small style
- -Setting the layout_centerVertical to true

Comment: Is @drawable/button a nine-patch? Does the nine-patch have a properly defined content area?

Comment: @npace, The drawable/button is an xml shape drawable with stoke, corners and gradient. Do you want me to post the code for that?

Comment: Well it might be a bug with the way the drawable is being rendered... but if I were you, I'd just use a 9-patch image for this.